# How to list all the logs with response time greater the 6000 msecs

Tags: linux, awk, grep, uwsgi

```
[pid: 28785|app: 0|req: 2291/4303] 192.168.115.161 () {38 vars in 1198 bytes} [Sun Aug 26 12:43:42 2018] GET /v1/posts/ => generated 62220 bytes in 1744 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 9 headers in 380 bytes (1 switches on core 3)
```

I'm using 'grep' to search the logs.

```
grep '[6-9]{4,} msecs' /var/log/wsgi/wsgi.log
```

Please help me to filter all the logs with response time greater than 6 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than just 1 line, show a few lines of sample input (some that do and some that don't satisfy your search criteria, especially any you think will be hard for a tool to handle correctly) and the associated expected output given that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to do a numeric comparison using a regexp, use a tool that understands numbers, e.g. awk. If this isn't all you need:

```
awk '$24>6000' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
[pid: 28785|app: 0|req: 2291/4303] 192.168.115.161 () {38 vars in 1198 bytes} [Sun Aug 26 12:43:42 2018] GET /v1/posts/ => generated 62220 bytes in 1744 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 9 headers in 380 bytes (1 switches on core 3)
[pid: 28785|app: 0|req: 2291/4303] 192.168.115.161 () {38 vars in 1198 bytes} [Sun Aug 26 12:43:42 2018] GET /v1/posts/ => generated 62220 bytes in 5744 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 9 headers in 380 bytes (1 switches on core 3)
[pid: 28785|app: 0|req: 2291/4303] 192.168.115.161 () {38 vars in 1198 bytes} [Sun Aug 26 12:43:42 2018] GET /v1/posts/ => generated 62220 bytes in 6744 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 9 headers in 380 bytes (1 switches on core 3)

$ awk '$24>6000' file
[pid: 28785|app: 0|req: 2291/4303] 192.168.115.161 () {38 vars in 1198 bytes} [Sun Aug 26 12:43:42 2018] GET /v1/posts/ => generated 62220 bytes in 6744 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 9 headers in 380 bytes (1 switches on core 3)
```

then edit your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with concise, testable sample input and expected output.